# Accurev SCM Performance Very Slow on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, accurev

I'm the Accurev administrator at work.  I have one of my users on Mac OSX that is having really bad performance - it takes about 45 seconds between launching the app and displaying the login screen.  It takes 8 seconds to run "accurev info".  Our server is version 5.3a and the client is version 5.3b.  We had the same issue on version 4.7.  We opened a support case a month ago and have had a lot of back and forth.

**Here's the hardware information**

- Model Name: iMac
- Model Identifier: iMac11,3
- Processor Name: Intel Core i7
- Processor Speed: 2.93 GHz
- Number Of Processors: 1
- Total Number Of Cores: 4
- L2 Cache (per core): 256 KB
- L3 Cache: 8 MB
- Memory: 8 GB
- Processor Interconnect Speed: 4.8 GT/s
- Boot ROM Version: IM112.0057.B00
- SMC Version (system): 1.59f2

**Here's the output from "accurev diag"**

- Basic CPU : 108233.76
- Host name resolution : 286.69
- Memory : 582.40
- Guaranteed disk write : 135.52 MBytes/sec
- Network read : 11.20 MBytes/sec, 11472.14 KBytes/sec
- Available network bandwidth is equivalent to typical 100Mbit LAN
- Network write : 10.72 MBytes/sec, 10973.83 KBytes/sec
- Available network bandwidth is equivalent to typical 100Mbit LAN

All other application are really quick on this machine.  I have a Macbook Pro with an i7 and 4GB Ram and accurev works great on it.  That said, I'm not a Mac expert.

I'm at a loss and this user is really becoming frustrated.  Do any of you have suggestions?

Thanks in advance for reading this question.

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the support case ID so I could look into the history?  My first inclination would be to isolate if it's the accurev client in general or limited to the Java GUI.  How long does it take run commands like "accurev show -fx depots" from a command shell, compared to opening the list of depots in the GUI, for example?

If it turns out to be the AccuRev client in general, is it possible that there is some kind of duplexing going on from the client machine over the network?  I've seen this happen via VoIP phones.  The "accurev diag" output makes this seem less likely though.  Have you tried having them delete their "preferences.xml" file that lives in the user's .accurev directory under their home directory?

Just some thoughts...
~James

Comment: "accurev show -fx depots" took six seconds.  At your suggestion, I had him delete the preferences.xml and it didn't change the performance.  I tried deleting the entire .accurev folder and still no change.  The case number is SPT-14205.

Comment: Thanks Monte.  I looked at the notes of the case.  It does appear to be some environmental factor outside the realm of what we'd normally expect.  I think any feedback/troubleshooting I could provide here would be redundant, I'd suggest continuing to work it through in the case, although I'll begin monitoring it to help accelerate a solution...

Comment: The issue turned out to be a name resolution problem. The getipnodebyname call was taking about 2 seconds and it appears that Accurev uses the call often.   

The fix was to add his local machine's name into the /etc/hosts file for quicker resolution.